# Should a closed cone be regarded closed surface?

Tags: geometry

If i enclose the flat surface of the cone then is the cone a closed surface ? Ive read that cones aren't closed surfaces now if the flat isn't a vaccum then should the cone be regarded as closed surface?

Comment: What do you think? Is it homeomorphic to the closed sphere?

Answer (score 1):

A cone with its vertex and a single nappe without its base is open, smooth and continuous.

Yes, with its vertex and single nappe  when base is included it is a closed surface but has discontinuous slope at its base circle rim.

Comment: Rather than rim if i put a circular  plate would  it be closed?

Answer (score 0):

No,  if I close the base of cone it is a hollow shape only.  If we see as volume based, filled object if closed and unfilled is hollow.